# Get request for 1 specific user from mysql in java

Tags: java, mysql, get

I have a MySQL database (called database) with tables: event, gebruiker and situatie. Now I need to write code in Java (using netbeans) to test my restful webservice. I'm able to retrieve all users (=gebruikers, dutch), but when I want to retrieve one specific user by searching on it's primary key 'Username', I get this 500-error when testing the restful webservice. please help!
this is my code in java:

```
@Stateless
@Path("gebruikers")
public class GebruikerService {

@Resource(name = "jdbc/socialebuurt")
private DataSource source;

/*
 * Request all users.
 */

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Gebruiker> getGebruikers() {
    try (Connection conn = source.getConnection()) {
        try (PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM gebruiker")) {
            try (ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery()) {
                List<Gebruiker> results = new ArrayList<>();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Gebruiker g = new Gebruiker();
                    g.setUsername(rs.getString("Username"));
                    g.setNaam(rs.getString("Naam"));
                    g.setVoornaam(rs.getString("Voornaam"));
                    g.setStraat(rs.getString("Straat"));
                    g.setHuisNr(rs.getInt("huisnr"));
                    g.setPostcode(rs.getInt("postcode"));
                    g.setGemeente(rs.getString("gemeente"));
                    g.setWachtwoord(rs.getString("wachtwoord"));
                    results.add(g);
                }
                return results;
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(ex);
    }
}


/*
 * Request one specific user.
 */

@Path("{username}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Gebruiker getGebruiker(@PathParam("username") String username) {
    try (Connection conn = source.getConnection()) {
        try (PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM gebruiker WHERE username = ?")) {
            stat.setString(1,"");
            try (ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery()) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    Gebruiker ge = new Gebruiker();
                    ge.setUsername(rs.getString("Username"));
                    ge.setNaam(rs.getString("Naam"));
                    ge.setVoornaam(rs.getString("Voornaam"));
                    ge.setStraat(rs.getString("Straat"));
                    ge.setHuisNr(rs.getInt("huisnr"));
                    ge.setPostcode(rs.getInt("postcode"));
                    ge.setGemeente(rs.getString("gemeente"));
                    ge.setWachtwoord(rs.getString("wachtwoord"));
                    return ge;
                } else {
                    throw new WebApplicationException(Status.NOT_FOUND);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(ex);
    }
}
}
```

Table 'gebruiker' has following attributes: username (primary key, varchar(26)), naam (text), voornaam (text), straat (text), huisNr (int(11)), postcode (int(4)), gemeente (text), wachtwoord (text).
If more info is needed, please ask.
Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

You needs to have a [`WHERE`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm) clause in your statement, like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM gebruiker WHERE username =" + username;
```